# Js replace slashes in string

Tags: javascript

I have url that i need to change to a valid slashes.

```
var url = data\14/loto/posts.json
```

I need this to change to this:

```
data/14/loto/posts.json
```

But this is not working:

```
url.replace('\', '/');
```

Comment: Escape the slash using a double slash.

Comment: If you didn't see the `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal` error message, please find your browser's JavaScript console. It's a basic tool to debug JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JS, you need to escape backslashes, because they are normally escape characters themselves.

`url.replace('\\', '/');`

Additionally, if you want to escape multiple backslashes in the same string, use a regex literal with the `g` flag, "g" standing for "global".

`url.replace(/\\/g, '/');`

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
var url = "data\\14/loto/posts.json" // "\\" is because slash should be escaped, otherwise your url isn't a valid string
url = url.replace(/\\/g, '/');
```